# How to get full cmd of a process in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

My process cmd is very long because there are lots of arguments. Now I would like to check the full cmd. By using `cat /proc/PROCESS_NUMBER/cmdline`, the cmd is not fully shown. Is there any other way to see exactly full cmd in linux?

Comment: Have you tried `ps -efwwww | grep <command name>`?

Comment: Just tried. This will give the same commandline length as `cat /proc/PROCESS_NUMBER/cmdline` Thanks for let me know more about `ps` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long is your command line?

If it is in the megabyte range, you might perhaps recompile your kernel with a bigger `ARG_MAX` in your `linux-3.*/include/linux/limits.h` file. I put there

```
#define ARG_MAX  2097152    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
```

<sup>(there might also be a way to set that limit dynamically, but I forgot how, and I could be wrong)</sup>

I do like big `ARG_MAX` limit because I occasionally use the `**/*.c` global expansion feature of `zsh` which is my interactive shell.

Don't put a huge value in `ARG_MAX`; I would guess that you want to have it less than 2% of your available RAM.

Notice that `/proc/*/cmdline` contains null bytes. You might translate them, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6133243/841108).

#### addenda

if for whatever reason you cannot afford a large command line, find some way and convention to avoid having such a large amount of program arguments. For instance, you could modify the invoked program to read some things from a file or some other source (database?). For example, some Unix programs (e.g. GCC) accept `@`*filename* to read options from some file named *filename*.

Comment: This way looks cool~ But this host is a prod host and I have no rights to re-compile kernel. The commandline length is far from megabyte. It is about 10k at most. Is there a easy with less impact to host to do this? Thanks~